# Is hovering over a <h1> and changing value of <p> possible using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the value of a `<p>` after hovering over an `<h1>` only using CSS?

When the user hovers over a heading, I want the color value of a `<p>` element to change accordingly. I'd like to achieve this using only CSS.

Comment: Yeh, give me 5 mins.... actually, what do you mean by value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: is `p` is after `h1` you can use `h1:hover + p { /* styles */ }` code

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can. Here is an example.

```
 #a:hover ~ #b {
background: #ccc;
   }

<h1 id="a">Heading</h1>
<p id="b">random Text</p>
```

But element with id b must be after a.

Hope that was Helpful!

Comment: if you have 10 of these on a page, you'd have 10 different selector expressions... not very robust

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me a lot. I was wondering if it is possible to click on the id a and have the changes on b staying. If it is possible, how is it done?

Comment: you need javascript to do that. Here [link](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-change-text-color-when-clicking-in-another-div/) you can read about it.

Answer (score 0):

if the `h1` directly precedes the `<p>` tag, you could do something like:

```
h1:hover + p { color:red; }
```

Note that IE needs a `<!doctype>` before it will honor hover on elements other than `<a>`, and the `+` selector does not work in IE 6

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but requires a sort of "hack". My advice would be to go with JavaScript, JQuery for this action, much easier.

Comment: suggesting a 93K javascript library because pure CSS would be a "hack"... Bold strategy, Cotton

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this question as changing the actual value inside the `<p>` element. If that's the case here is how it can be done.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fc3rhgow/1/

HTML:

```
<h1 id="myH1">this is the h1</h1>
<p id="myP">this is the p</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("myH1");
var myP = document.getElementById("myP");

h1.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);

function mouseOver(){
    myP.innerHTML = "new value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this decision will suit you. Good luck.

```css
h1:hover + p:before{
  content:'Ohhh hover h1';
  }
h1 + p:before{
  content:'h1 no hover ';
  }
```

```html
<h1>Header H1</h1>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you mean by 'value', and what your HTML looks likes (ie, which p element you wish to modify) you can do something like...

```
h1:hover p
{
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

OR maybe this?

```
h1:hover ~ p
{
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

OR this perhaps?

```
div h1:hover p
{
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

OR maybe even this?

```
h1:hover > div p
{
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Whatever you need to to target mate...

***NB: As far as I know, we can't target parent selectors :-(***

Comment: This way the `p` must be inside of the `h1`.. not really a good idea.

Comment: He hadn't said otherwise... its a snippet for him/her to investigate, geez

Comment: I think you might be confusing immediate child selector (`>`) with the adjacent sibling selector (`+`)

Comment: ??? Without any HTML provided and not knowing which <p> he wishes to manipulate, I think this answer is a fair, well rounded one. What makes you think I'm getting confused with these selectors?

Comment: @AdamJeffers I just meant that all your examples except the second one rely on the `p` being within the `h1`, and the second one will change the color of all the `p` tags on the page that come after the `h1` being hovered over. I did not downvote you, btw

Comment: Valid point, we have no way of targeting parents as far as I know? Ill add that to my answer